# MySQL - Date Format from 'yyyy-mm-mm' to 'yyyy-mm' in a function

Tags: mysql, date, format

I created a function that returns a date in a different format from the original.
Basically, I am testing with this `Select MonthSub('2014-04-10',2)`# statement, and it should return
`2014-02`, instead of `2014-02-10`.

Could someone check my code and see what I am doing is wrong? 
If I do anything to format by using `date_format(new_in_date, '%y-%m')` it returns this error:

```
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect date value: '2014-02' for column 'new_in_date' at row 1
```

The function I wrote:

```
Create function MonthSub (in_date date, in_mn_adjust int)
    returns date
Begin
    declare new_in_date date default in_date;
    set new_in_date := date_sub(new_in_date, interval in_mn_adjust month);
    return new_in_date;
end;
```

Comment: You mean yyyy-mm-dd in title?

Comment: What you want is, given a date, substract a number of months and return only year-month. Do I understand correctly? (e.g.: `MonthSub('2014-04-10', 2)` means "Substract two months and return only `yyyy-mm`; in this case, `2014-02` )

Comment: if you want to use `date_format` in the function, you need to `returns varchar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you want your function to do is:

1. Given a date `d` and a number `n`, you want to substract `n` months to `d`
2. Then you want to return only the year and month of the date

So, you can do the following:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac47a/1)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
create function MonthSub(d date, n int) 
returns varchar(50) -- You're not returning a date, but a string 
                    -- ('yyyy-mm' is not a date)
begin
  declare t date;
  declare ans varchar(50);
  set t = date_add(d, interval -(day(d)-1) day); -- Substract the days 
                                                 -- to avoid problems with things 
                                                 -- like 'February 30th'
  set t = date_add(t, interval -n month); -- Substract the months
  set ans = date_format(t, '%Y-%m'); -- Format the date to 'yyyy-mm'
  return ans; -- Return the date
end //
```

**Query 1**:

```
-- Test it!
select MonthSub('2014-05-02', 2)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac47a/1/0)**:

```
| MONTHSUB('2014-05-02', 2) |
|---------------------------|
|                   2014-03 |
```

Comment: Ah!! yes this is great. I thought about making it into string, then thought it was a bit far-fetched.. I guess that's a way to do it. Thanks a ton!!!